# Configuration Error in iis Could not load file or assembly and An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: this

Configuration Error Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'dll file' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Answer (score 1):

**open iss manager** 
click on application pools => then right click on defaultAppPool => select advanced settings=> and 'true' the Enabled 32 bit application pool on General section.